# EFCore query to get amount of products for each vendor by product search term

Tags: postgresql, linq, e-commerce

I'm stuck on a product search query for a price comparison website.

There are 3 Tables:

**Product:**
`ProductId`, `Title`

**Vendor:**
`VendorId`

**ProductPrices:**
`ProductId`, `VendorId`, `Price`

ProductPrices is a mapping table for all vendor prices for a certain product.

Now I want to be able to search for a product like "sweater blue". This should get all vendors that selling products containing the word "sweater blue" and the number of products found for each vendor.

The output should be:

```
{[

{VendorA,Found:23},
{VendorB,Found:2},

}}
```

By now I only have this query for getting all vendors by a products search term:

```
            var query = Context.Products
                        .Join(Context.ProductPrices,
                            product => product.ProductId,
                            pprice => pprice.ProductId,
                            (product, pprice) => new { product, pprice })
                        .Join(Context.Vendors,
                            pprice2 => pprice2.pprice.VendorId,
                            vendor => vendor.VendorId,
                            (pprice2, vendor) => new { pprice2, vendor })
                        .Where(x=>x.pprice2.product.Title.Contains("sweater blue"))
                        .Distinct()
                        .Select(x=>new
                        {
                            x.vendor
                        });
```

I don't know how to get the counts found for each vendor in `ProductPrices`.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to use `GroupBy` on `vendor` after filtering (without `Distinct`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use just **Product** and **productPrices** tables, Like the following code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> result = (from product in Context.Products
    join productPrice in Context.ProductPrices on product.ProductId equals productPrice.ProductId
    where product.Title == "sweater blue"
    select new { VendorId = productPrice.VendorId, Tilte = product.Title }
    )
    .GroupBy(v => v.VendorId)
    .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => $"Found : {v.ToList().Count}");
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response.
when i run this query i get the following error:

System.InvalidOperationException: Client side GroupBy is not supported.

Comment: Try to separate the code, like ````var result1 = (from product in products
join productPrice in products1 on product.ProductId equals productPrice.ProductId
where product.Title == "sweater blue"
select new { VendorId = productPrice.VendorId, Tilte = product.Title }).ToList();
Dictionary<string, string> result2 = result1.GroupBy(v => v.VendorId).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => $"Found : {v.ToList().Count}");````

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much.
I just added some additional code to get the complete Vendor object in response:

.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => new { a = $"Found : {v.ToList().Count}", b = v.Select(x => x.Vendor).FirstOrDefault() });